# Error handling in 'object oriented' python

Tags: python, error-handling

So I have a python function:

```
def send_data():
    return instance.handleData(otherinstance.getData())
```

In one class I have `getData`, a function that obtains data and returns it in a dict:

```
def getData(self):
    data = self.makeRequest('data')
    latestData = data['values'][0]
    return latestData
```

Afterwards that dict (`latestData`) will be used in a function form another class where the values will be formatted properly:

```
def handleData(self, data):
    handledData = {}
    handledData['name'] = data.get('display', 'display not set')
    # some other stuff...       
    return handledData
```

at the end, the returned value from `handleData` will be passed to JavaScript by `send_data`, which should show a proper error message on my html page in case there is no data / the data is not complete.

I'd like to find out what the best way of error handling would be here, should I first raise a `KeyError` exception in `getData()`? if so, what should then be passed over to `handleData`? Just an error code that implies there is no data, that will be sent back to `send_data`? The thing is, I must know  the error in JavaScript somehow, to show a proper message (e.g. 'no values found')

Comment: Where do you think some data will be missing? Are you expecting that in the `getData` function, the `data` might not have the `values` key, or it might not contain an element as the index `0`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no problem in passing strings into JV, personally I would handle the error in Python:

```
try:
    # do something
except ValueError: # give a specific error if possible
    # exception()
    # possibly passing an error message to JV
else:
    # do other something
```

, check this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) for types of errors and exceptions.

And than I would just pass a string to JV ensuring that no error (or error management besides dealing with strings) would be in JV. This is, off course, assuming the bulk of your code is in Python.

My opinion is based in my own preferences from software design. I rather have Python dealing with Python errors, than having JV interpreting Python errors (although it does seem a valid possibility).

I think if you mix it up to much you'll loose readability, as well it will get more difficult for a JV developer to work with the code (assuming it wouldn't be familiar with Python). Conclusion: I would keep Python as hidden as possible if my front is in JV.